# Jupyter Notebook not running in Microsoft Visual Studio Code, VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to run Jupyter notebook on VS code all of a sudden. It was running fine like a week ago before VS code updated recently, but all of sudden it has stopped.
Now when try to run for example `print ('hello World')` in a newly created Jupyter notebook, I get error **"can't open file"**. Can someone please help. Below are additional details:

Machine : Windows 10 Pro |
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.80 GHz |
System Type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor |
Visual Studio Code Version: 1.84.2 |
Python version: 3.11.6.

**Error I'm getting**

```
C:\Users\myComputer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe: **can't open file** 'C:\\Users\\Untitled-1.ipynb': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Basically whatever folder location I choose to open, when I go to Command Palette --> and Click --> "Create New Jupyter Notebook" --> it puts double slash ( as shown in above error) C:\Users\Untitled-1.ipynb. I think it might be due to this double "\" but I'm neither sure of it nor I am able to resolve this.

**Steps I tried:**

- Tried installing Anaconda navigator and tried to use Base Conda to run jyputer notebook on vs code, did not work for me and earlier i didn't have to run jupyter notebook from anaconda to make it work in vs code
- Restarted my machine at each step.
- Uninstalled VS code from all places and reinstalled it from microsoft store
- ```
   Steps to uninstall VS code from Windows: Delete %APPDATA%\Code and %USERPROFILE%\.vscode.
  ```
- uninstall python and reinstalled it from microsoft store
- installed jupyter notebook and python vs code extensions from vscode
- also tried installing jupyter notebook through pip, `python -m pip install jupyter notebook -U`
- upgraded pip also

**Error I'm getting**

```
C:\Users\myComputer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\Untitled-1.ipynb': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Basically whatever folder location I choose to open, when I go to Command Palette --> and Click --> "Create New Jupyter Notebook" --> it puts double slash ( as shown in above error) C:\Users\Untitled-1.ipynb. I think it might be due to this double "\" but I'm neither sure of it nor I am able to resolve this.

I have also check multiple thread on stack overflow about this issue still couldn't resolve it

**Error image**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDBGl.png)

Comment: I think you shouldn't use the `C:\Users` folder as your default folder. Try open another folder outside of the `C:\Users` folder. Such as `C:\Projects`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem on my Windows 11 machine.

Comment: I can't find a related issue ticket from googling "`site:github.com vscode jupyter "can't open file" "untitled"`". You might want to consider raising one using the `Help > Report Issue` menu item in VS Code. If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.

Comment: @WillHuang - thanks for trying will, it does not matter which location I use, issue persists. For example: If I create an ipynb file as save it in C:\Users\myPc\Documents\my_new_jupyterNb.ipynb , I still get the same error, that it can not read my file, Error will look something like this as I tried similar approach and was showing in my original question just an example on my Windows 10 machine. Here is the error: 
C:\Users\myComputer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\myPC\\my_new_jupyterNb.ipynb': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, it was an issue to with my key bindings in vscode for jupyter notebook, rest everything was working correctly.